# How to read data generated from REST API in a Javascript file and use it another?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to make my first web application and have run into some problems when I'm trying to "glue" all the parts together.

I have three files:
getData.js - has a function main() which does some calls to a REST API and manipulates the data and returns an array with ready to use data. This works fine by itself.

getData.js:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

var tag = "BQDmciWElpq393aJqhpUOjX_V0kSJFp2zLS1ycH4piTl9rNOFjCsjKqHUXTfzv3hXGU3ELM3k8bS6WQzMKnDNygLlzaLmvo2v28pOGCI4KFzEY3jm3MUImBezBQ1-wU9IK2MYo1CXwnXAq3OLMa4TkeM76iQK2kD4nE"

async function getUserPlaylists(input){
    const url = input;
    const options = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Bearer ".concat(tag)
      }
    };

    const result = fetch(url,options)
      .then(result => result.json())
      return result;
}

async function getPlaylistIdFromUsersPlaylists(item) {
  var temp = [];
  item.forEach(async function(it){
    await temp.push(it['id']);
  });
  return temp;
}

async function getAllTracks(playlists) {
  var temp = [];
  await Promise.all(playlists.map(async (playlist) => {
      var result = await getPlaylistTracks("https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/"+playlist+"/tracks");
      temp.push(...Object.values(result)[1]);

      while(result['next'] !== null){
        let temp2 = await getPlaylistTracks(result['next']);
        temp.push(...Object.values(temp2)[1]);
        result = temp2;
      }
  }));
  return temp;
}

async function getPlaylistTracks(link) {
  const url = link;
  const options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer ".concat(tag)
    }
  };

  const result = fetch(url,options)
    .then(result => result.json())
    return result;
}


async function getAllArtists(tracklist){
  var map = new Map();

  tracklist.forEach(function(track){

    //get all artists
    var trackArtists = track['track']['artists'];

    //for all artists
    trackArtists.forEach(function(artist){

      //if artist is in hashMap add +1 to key
      if(map.has(artist['id'])){
        map.set(artist['id'], map.get(artist['id'])+1);

      //else add new artists with value 1
      }else {
        map.set(artist['id'], 1);
      }
    })
  })
  return map;
}

async function createDataFromMap(map){
  var ret = [];
  for (let [id, value] of map) {
    ret.push({id: id, value: value});
  }

  ret.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a['value'] > b['value']) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a['value'] < b['value']) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });

  return ret.slice(0,50);
}

async function getNamesAndImages(ids) {
  var temp = [];
  await Promise.all(ids.map(async (id) => {

      var result = await getArtist("https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/"+id['id']);
      temp.push({'id': id['id'], 'name': result['name'], 'value': id['value'], 'image': result['images'][0]});
      //console.log(result);
  }));

  temp.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a['value'] > b['value']) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (a['value'] < b['value']) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  });
  return temp;
}

async function getArtist(link) {
  const url = link;
  const options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer ".concat(tag)
    }
  };

  const result = fetch(url,options)
    .then(result => result.json())
    return result;
}



const main = async () => {
  console.log("hej");
  //get all user playlists in an array of playlists
  var listsOfPlaylists = [];
  let temp = await getUserPlaylists("https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/juliusraphael/playlists");
  listsOfPlaylists.push(...Object.values(temp)[1]);

  while(temp['next'] !== null){
    let temp2 = await getUserPlaylists(temp['next']);
    listsOfPlaylists.push(...Object.values(temp2)[1]);
    temp = temp2;
  }

  //get all playlist ids in an array
  var playlists = await getPlaylistIdFromUsersPlaylists(listsOfPlaylists);

  //for all playlists get all tracks in each playlist
  var tracks = await getAllTracks(playlists);

  //get all artitst from tracks and put in hashmap
  var artistsHashmap = await getAllArtists(tracks);
  //console.log(artistsHashmap);

  var ids = await createDataFromMap(artistsHashmap);

  var data = await getNamesAndImages(ids);
  console.log(data);

  return data;
};
```

renderChart.js - this uses d3 library to paint a bubble chart with images.

```
const DATA = await main();

var width = 800;
var height = 800;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("x", d3.forceX(width / 2).strength(0.05))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(height / 2).strength(0.05))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(function(d) {
    return radiusScale(d.value);
  }));

var radiusScale = d3.scaleSqrt().domain([1,300]).range([10,100]);

const svg = d3.select('svg')
  .classed('container', true);

var defs = svg.append('defs');

defs.selectAll('.artist-pattern')
  .data(DATA)
  .enter().append('pattern')
  .attr('class', 'artist-pattern')
  .attr('id', function(d){
    return d.id;
  })
  .attr('height', '100%')
  .attr('width', '100%')
  .attr('patternContentUnits', 'objectBoundingBox')
  .append('image')
  .attr('height', 1)
  .attr('width', 1)
  .attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'none')
  .attr('xlink:href', function(d){
    return d.image.url;
  });


var circles = svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(DATA)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr('r', function(d){
    return radiusScale(d.value)
  })
  .attr('fill', function(d){
    return "url(#"+ d.id +")";
  });

simulation.nodes(DATA)
  .on('tick', ticked);

function ticked(){
  circles
    .attr('transform', function(d){
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    })
}
```

index.html - looks like following...

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>D3.js</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      width: 800px;
      height: 800px;
    }
    .bar {
      fill: #b2d8d8;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="getData.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-dispatch.v1.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-quadtree.v1.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-timer.v1.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-force.v2.min.js" defer></script>
  <script src="renderChart.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>


  <svg></svg>


</body>
</html>
```

If i hardcode som data into the DATA var in renderChart.js and executed the index.html it renders everything correctly. What I now want to do instead when the index.html is executed is to first run the main() method in getData.js to generate the data and use that data in renderChart.js.
I've tried to google a solution but I'm afraid that my terminology isn't good enough to find a proper answer.

EDIT: I added the code for the other files and "script src="getData.js" defer" to the .html

Cheers / Julius

Comment: why don't you call or initiate d3.js chart when you have the data in your main function() ? when you have your data ready bind the chart then. From example its unclear what are you doing in your main or what renderchart code looks like. Please state that as well in question.

Comment: I've added the code to the original post.

Answer (score -1):

Add in `<script src="getData.js" defer></script>` next to the other scripts.
Then export the `main()` method in `getData.js` and then you will be able to call it from the `renderChart.js` file.

Comment: The main() function is using other functions in the getData.js files, will I have to export all of them as well?

Comment: Nope, only need to export what you are going to later be calling, the main can then access all the stuff in that file.

In fact, if getData.js isn't set up as a module, you may not need to export it at all!
Give it a try with just adding the script tag, and see what happens when you try to run main() from in render.

Comment: Hm it still doesn't work. I edited the original post and added the code to the other files. When I run the .html it doesnt seem to run the main function, I don't see any prints in the console that I add in the begining of the main function.

Comment: What happens when you just copy and paste the code all into one file? Does it work then?

Comment: Nope it also doesn't work if copy and paste the code from the getData file but still uses the hardcode data for DATA var

Comment: I would keep everything in one file for now, pepper `console.logs` around, and figure out why the DATA is not being populated.
Your issue isn't linking two files, if everything being in one file isn't working, that suggests something else.